# Throw a customized error when more chars than expected are passed in a SQL function attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, attributes

I have created a SQL Server function like that:

```
function [schema].[function_name]
     (@ids varchar(5))
```

but when I call it like with an `@ids` attribute with more chars than expected e.g.,

```
select * 
from db.schema.function_name('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST')
```

I get no error. How can I throw a customized error in that case? Such as "you passed more chars than expected".

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: use `char` that limits the input

Comment: @Firewizz this does trigger an error

Comment: https://www.dbbest.com/blog/exception-sql-server-udf

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple

```
create function dbo.test
(
@id varchar(30)
)
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
if len(@id)>10
begin
return 'Length exceeded'
end

return 1

end
```

**Testing :**

```
select dbo.test(replicate('a',14))
```

returns

```
Length exceeded
```